# Coordinates for the points of the densest hexagonal lattice that can be fit in a bounding box?

Tags: geometry

What is the densest hexagonal lattice, with a lattice point to lattice point spacing of $s$, that I can fit in or along the contour of a $A \times B$ bounding box?  How would I generate a list of coordinates for the points in this lattice?